# mongoose update fields and add new field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I already googled a lot but unfortunately, I'm unable to solve my problem...
I've some documents in my MongoDB and now I added a new optional field to my mongoose schema. Unfortunately, I cannot update my existing documents with this new field.

```
MyModel.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.modelId, {$set: req.body}, {new: true})
```

This only updates the existing fields but unfortunately it doesn't add the new field.
How can I force mongoose to add the new field to the document?

---

**Update:** My mistake. My schemas are having their own repository because I'm sharing them between different projects. I forgot to update them in the respective project. Now everything works perfect.

Comment: You are using mongoose. Did you add the new field to the schema definition?

Comment: @ema Yes, I've added the new field to my schema definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should update the document like this:

```
Model.update({_id :req.body.modelId },{$set : {new_field: "value"}})
```

Mongoose is probably doing something between, so it is better to bypass it.

Comment: As `update` is deprecated, better use now `updateMany` and it works in the same work with same syntax.